# Domain name resolution on all network interfaces fails when default gateway becomes unreachable

Tags: linux, networking, dns, routing

I have two network interfaces configured in Linux and running at the same time:

- WiFi (wlan0)
- LTE modem (modem1)

The wlan0 interface has a higher priority (lower metric) in the routing table (output of `ip route`)

```
default via 192.168.36.1 dev wlan0 metric 600 
default dev modem1 scope link metric 1144
```

The /etc/resolv.conf has the Google DNS server as the first nameserver (the second entry is the gateway of the WiFi router):

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 192.168.36.1
```

I can normally ping any domain through both interfaces

```
ping -I wlan0 google.com  # Success
ping -I modem1 google.com  # Success
```

Now to the question: It happens that the WiFi connection signal gets bad and the gateway 192.168.36.1 becomes unreachable, but the *wlan0* interface is still up and I still have an IP address on it. This is the output of `ip route` - note the *linkdown* for *wlan0*:

```
default via 192.168.36.1 dev wlan0 metric 600 linkdown
default dev modem1 scope link metric 1144
```

In this case `ping` using *wlan0* does not work anymore, but ping using *modem1* works, but it only works if I supply an IP address:

```
ping -I wlan0 8.8.8.8  # FAIL
ping -I modem1 8.8.8.8  # Success
```

The following (and any attempt to connect to any domain as well) fails with a "Temporary failure in name resolution":

```
ping -I modem1 google.com  # FAIL
```

If I set the *wlan0* interface down, the name resolution works without problems (note this also removes the first line from the routing table above).

My assumption of what could be happening is that the name resolution is not happening via the *modem1* interface, but it just uses the routing table, in which case it ends up on the unreachable gateway of *wlan0* because that is the route with the lowest metric. Only the ping itself runs through *modem1*, which is successful.

Is this assumption to some degree correct? If yes, what could be done to actually run the name resolution through the *modem1* interface?

Comment: See if this helps: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345862/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-default-gateways-for-outbound-connections

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398810/default-route-with-linkdown

By default, routes with *linkdown* are not ignored and therefore the name resolution was still trying to be done via the unreachable route.